# How to use multi thread to start a web app before I run test cases for this target web?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng, integration-testing

Hi I am working on integration tests for a web application and I am using TestNG and Maven. I made a test suite including all my test cases. In order to start the web app before all tests running, I start the web application in the @BeforeSuite annotated method as this:

```
@BeforeSuite
  public void prepareTestContext() {
    ConfigServer.main();  //This is a spring boot web app.
  }
```

Now I want to start this web application in a another thread, I am new to multi threading programing, could anyone please tell me how should I get this done with another thread? Thanks.

Comment: What build system are you using? With Maven, you generally start your application in `pre-integration-test` and then run tests in `integration-test`. Note also that Spring Boot has **extensive** built-in support for integration tests, and you should generally use their runners instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using maven.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
@BeforeSuite
public void prepareTestContext() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConfigServer.main();
        }
    },"web-app-runner").start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when running tests like this in Maven, use the `integration-test` phase with Failsafe. In the `pre-integration-test` phase, you set up whatever environment is necessary, including starting up the application (maybe a Docker container with a test database, too), then run tests in `integration-test`, then shut down your test context in `post-integration-test`.

With Spring Boot, however, all of this functionality is already supported by Boot itself, including features like the ability to only start up the "slice" of your application actually needed for a test. Take a look at the `@SpringBootTest` annotation and [the Spring blog article on the latest test enhancements](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4).